# Mamp-Pro SSL for local virtualhost

Tags: ssl, mamp-pro

I've seen a lot of similar questions but none of the answers helped me (and there's one addition I didn't see anywhere).

So, I'm using Mamp-Pro 6.0.1 for local testing. I have a domain set up ([www.mydomain.lo](http://www.mydomain.lo)), enabled SSL and used a self signed certificate I created with the button in Mamp.
I added the cert to my keychain (I'm on a Mac) and set it to «always trust» in the keychain-info.

But when I try to access the local page with https://www.mydomain.lo, I get an error saying:

There was an error connecting to … SSL received an entry which exceeds the max allowed length. Error-Code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

(this is loosely translated from German).

The page works with http:// but I'd like to test the SSL-Version, too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to partly solve this riddle.

SSL just doesn't work on local hosts, when the standard port (443) is used.

But it works when the «default MAMP ports» are used.

in MAMP-Pro got to «Ports & User» and click on «Set default MAMP ports».

The ports change as following:

```
Apache 8888 - SSL 8890
Nginx  7888 - SSL 7890
MySQL  8889
…
```

It is important that you don't change any of these. I tried to only change the Apache SSL port to 8890 and leave the other ports on their standard (Apache 80, MySQL 3306,…) but then the MySQL-Server doesn't respond.